# Publishing changes to a collection of observable objects

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I have an issue with propagating changes that happen to objects in the view model that are kept in an array.

I understand that `@Published` for a collection would work if the collection itself changes (eg. if elements were `struct` not `class`). Assuming that I need to preserve classes as classes. Is there a way to propagate events to a view, so that it knows it should be refreshed.

I have been trying all nasty ways like implementing `ObservableCollection` or `ObservableArray` but nothing seems to work.

Below an example of what I am struggling with.
Toggle is changing internally element of an array which has all the `ObservableObject` conformance and `@Published` annotation but still Text is not being refreshed.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(vm.texts.first!.text)
            .padding()
        
        Button("Toggle") {
            vm.texts.first?.toggle()
        }
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var texts: [TextHolder] = [.init(), .init()]
}

class TextHolder: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text: String = ""
    
    func toggle() {
        text = UUID().uuidString
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Did any of the three answers answer your question or offer your any help at all? I notice that none of them have any upvotes or comments.

Answer (score 2):

*Note: this is based on the requirement you listed of "Assuming that I need to preserve classes as classes" -- otherwise, making your model a struct gives you all of this behavior for free.*

You can call `objectWillChange.send()` manually on the `ObservableObject`. For example:

```
Button("Toggle") {
    vm.texts.first?.toggle()
    vm.objectWillChange.send()
}
```

Major downsides include having to add code to call this at each mutation site and actually remembering to do this. You could do things to compartmentalize the code a little more like moving `toggle` to the parent object and passing an index to it -- then, you could keep all of the `objectWillChange` calls in the parent. Also, you could experiment with KVO to watch the properties of the child objects and call `objectWillChange` when you see one of them change.

Answer (score 2):

Problem with your approach is that **TextHolder** is a class, which is a reference type. If you change any value in it, changes won't reflect to the array. That's why the SwiftUI view is not updated.

### Approach 1:

You can change **TextHolder** from class to struct. If you change any value in struct, a new copy is created. Your array will get the change to your SwiftUI view.

Please try below code

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()
        
    var body: some View {
        Text(vm.texts.first!.text)
            .padding()
            
        Button("Toggle") {
            vm.texts[0].toggle()
        }
    }
}
    
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var texts: [TextHolder] = [.init(), .init()]
}
    
struct TextHolder {
    var text: String = ""
        
    mutating func toggle() {
        text = UUID().uuidString
    }
}
```

### Approach 2:

After changing the value, you have to manually tell your **viewModel** that something is changed. Please refresh.

```swift
Button("Toggle") {
     vm.texts[0].toggle()
     vm.objectWillChange.send()
}
```

Hope it will help you understand.

Answer (score -1):

If you are not able to convert the class to a struct, an approach you can take is to subscribe to all `objectWillChange` publishers of the items in the array, and emit one for the main model, when one of those objects change:

```swift
@Published var texts: [TextHolder] = [.init(), .init()] {
    didSet {
        updateTextsSubscriptions()
    }
}

private var textsSubscriptions = [AnyCancellable]()

private func updateTextsSubscriptions() {
    textsSubscriptions = texts.map {
        $0.objectWillChange.sink(receiveValue: {
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        })
    }
}
```

You will also need to call `updateTextsSubscriptions` from within the initializer(s), to make sure any initial values for the `texts` array are monitored:

```swift
init() {
    updateTextsSubscriptions()
}
```